# Will I be able to get a US working visa, as someone who already works for a US company?

Tags: usa, working-visas

I've been working for a US based company for about 3 years now as a VP of Engineering, I'm a British citizen currently living in the UK, because of this I am engaged with the company as an independent contractor; I'm part of the founding team and am an equity shareholder.

It's becoming more and more challenging dealing with the timezone difference, assuming normal working hours, at best I get 4 hours overlap with the core team. I've been discussing with the company for a while now, the possibility of moving to the US. They are willing to sponsor me, but have no experience in doing so and want me to find out what's required.

Looking at the different types of visas - I have homed in on 2:

- H-1B: For this I would need a baccalaureate degree (which I don't), or be able to prove that I have >= 2-years professional experience (12+ years) and that there's no one available to do the job in the United States. Obviously have the experience, but the 'no one else' part is tricky; there are plenty of engineers in the US, but there's no one else on the planet that built our product's engine from scratch.
- L-1a: So these seem like a simpler route as at they are aimed at intra-company transfers. The trouble is this isn't necessarily an intra-company transfer, as even though I hold a title in the company, I am still technically an independent contractor.

It's very easy to get information on all of this, but I appear to be an a gray area and therefore would benefit from words of experience.

Would I qualify for one of the visa highlighted above? If not, is there another type of visa I have not considered.

Comment: Canada explicitly allows temporary visitors to work remotely for their foreign employers (unlike many countries including the US and the UK).  That won't help in the long term, but it does at least give you a way to spend some time working legally in the same time zone as tour US colleagues.

Comment: EB-3 is not a visa, it's a green card preference category. Your company would need to sponsor you for permanent residency. You are probably thinking of H1b. It is unlikely that you'd be able to qualify for L1, but should check with immigration attorney about your specific situation, maybe they can find a way.

Comment: @littleadv https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/employment-based-immigrant-visas.html

Comment: @phoog not sure what you're trying to say here

Comment: @littleadv that "green card preference categories" are also known as "immigrant visa categories."  Someone applying for immigration in that category will get a visa that says "IV category EB-3" unless they apply through adjustment of status.  Is the EB-3 category available only through adjustment of status?  If not, the statement "EB-3 is not a visa" is incorrect.

Comment: @phoog have you noticed that the site you linked to has no mention of EB-3? The DoS IV category is E-3, not EB-3 which is, as I said, a green card preference category used by the **USCIS**. USCIS, let me remind you, is **not** in business of issuing visas. Please stop harassing me.